# DLL Não encontrada

Tags: c#, visual-studio

ao executar minha aplicação, estou recendo o aviso de erro, informando  DAL.dll não foi encontrada. Não tenho ideia do que pode ser, estou seguindo um tutorial, esses são meus primeiros passos com C#. Estou usando VS 2017.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Editei a resposta. Tente seguir os passos da solução 1 agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pesquisando sobre o mesmo problema, consegui corrigir depois de algumas tentativas.

**Antes algumas explicações:**
A pasta bin recebe as `DLLs` do seu projeto após o Build da `Solution`.
Se você der um `Clean` no projeto, essas `DLLs` serão removidas até que um `Build` seja realizado novamente.

**Tente isso para corrigir:**
Clique com o botão direito em **Solution** na **Solution Explorer** -> **Properties** -> **Configuration Properties** e verifique se o checkbox **Build** está checado para cada uma das camadas.

Caso esteja checado e mesmo assim não esteja gerando as `DLLs`, siga os passos da **Solução 1** e se não funcionar tente a **Solução 2**:

### Solução 1

1. De um `Clean` em sua `Solution`
2. Clique com o botão direito sobre a camada da sua **aplicação** e, em `frammework`, verifique qual a versão está definida (no meu caso 4.5.1).
3. Vá na mesma opção do item **2** em todas as outras camadas e defina todos os `frameworks` para a mesma versão.
4. Salve seu projeto e de um `Build`

### Solução 2

1. De um `Clean`em sua `Solution`
2. Reinicie o `Visual Studio`
3. Desmarque os `Builds` conforme explicado anteriormente e clique em
   aplicar
4. Marque-os novamente novamente, clique em aplicar e Ok
5. De um `Build` em sua `Solution` e verifique se as `DLLs` foram
   geradas

Verifique [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found) no SOen com outras possíveis soluções.

Comment: Nada feito, persiste o mesmo problema. Pode ser um problema no visual studio 2017? Um amigo também tá fazendo esse mesmo exemplo e não teve esse problema.

Comment: Pode ter algo haver com a versão sim. Meu projeto que deu esse erro foi no VS 2013 no trabalho. Mas provável que seja algo no projeto e não no VS.
Ele usa em versão diferente da sua?

Comment: Sim, usa a versão 2015. Tô pensando em refazer a instalação, para versão 2015. Estou usando windows 10, será alguma incompatibilidade?

Comment: Não é o SO. Se quiser pode antes mandar seu projeto pra ele abrir no VS dele. Assim saberá se é algo no projeto ou na versão.

Comment: Blz farei isso. Assim que fizer, lhe informo. Muito obrigado​ pela ajuda. Abraços

Comment: George, consegui resolver. Era a versão do Net framework, na versão mais atual estava dando esse erro, alterei o projeto para usar a versão 4.5.1 e funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda. Abraços

Comment: Legal @LeonardoGuimarães, se te ajudou marque como como resposta no botão abaixo da votação ou, se utilizou outros passos, você pode postar sua solução e marcar como resposta para ajudar outros usuários.

Comment: Posso postar aqui como comentário? Ou tem um local específico? Sou novo nessa solução.

Comment: Se for apenas um adendo a resposta, pode ser comentário sim. Mas se necessário você pode responder sua própria questão. Se tiver dúvidas acesse o `Tour`.